# How to install sumo on Ubuntu 14.04(Trusty Tahr)?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I get the following error when trying to install sumo on Ubuntu 14.04(Trusty Tahr):

```
sumo : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not installable
```

I also have tried to install the package via synaptic but it doesn't work. I have installed libgdal1-1.10.1-grass and libgdal1h but the error persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `libgdal1` was available in saucy: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libgdal1

The package isn't in the trusty repos though.

You can add the (old) saucy repo to your sources.lst or try to download and install it manually.

**Important**: The package `sumo` from the trusty repo does not declare a dependency on `libgdal1`, but on `libgdal1h`, see here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sumo

Comment: That worked but the sumo version in trusty repo is outdated(0.19). I need to install sumo version 0.21 for veins 3.0 to work.